# AngularJS active class for navigation bar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, nav

I am pretty new to AngularJS so I'm doing an experiment. I want to change the active class of my navigation when I go to a new page. I want to make a specific controller variable for this,
HeaderCtrl is the controller, defined in the app.js file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name ePortfolioApp
 * @description
 * # ePortfolioApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
var app = angular.module('ePortfolioApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .when('/personality', {
        templateUrl: 'views/personality.html',
        controller: 'PersonalityCtrl'
      })
      .
      when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactCrl'
      })
      .when('/projects' ,{
        templateUrl: 'views/projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (evt, next, currentRoute) {
        $rootScope.isActive = next.$$route.routeName;
    }
  }

app.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.isActive = 'main';
}])

$rootScope.$watch('isActive', function() {
    $scope.isActive = $rootScope.isActive;
  });
```

My HTML has following code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li ng-class="isActive == 'main' ? 'active' : ' ' "><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li ng-class="isActive == 'about' ? 'active' : ' ' "><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
              <li ng-class="isActive == 'projects' ? 'active' : ' ' "><a ng-href="#/projects">Projects</a></li>
              <li ng-class="isActive == 'personality' ? 'active' : ' ' "><a ng-href="#/personality">Personality</a></li>
              <li ng-class="isActive == 'contact' ? 'active' : ' ' "><a ng-href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the controller of that HTML code? Are you sure the scope behind it has the proper isActive value?

Answer (score 1):

Basically `next.$$route` return array defined in `$routeProvider` when condition. For making you code working you need to do add `routeName` parameter into your each route which will make your code working.

**Code**

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    routeName: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    routeName: 'about'
  })
  .when('/personality', {
    templateUrl: 'views/personality.html',
    controller: 'PersonalityCtrl',
    routeName: 'personality'
  })
  .
  when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
    controller: 'ContactCrl',
    routeName: 'contact'
  })
  .when('/projects' ,{
    templateUrl: 'views/projects.html',
    controller: 'ProjectsCtrl',
    routeName: 'projects'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

In addition you need to put `$routeChangeStart` in a run block

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (evt, next, currentRoute) {
        $rootScope.isActive = next.$$route.routeName;
   }
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYRAYnTtsC3FYdsAgPed?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

personally i would use ui router and you can simply do

```
ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('contacts') }"
```